# Adding to an ArrayList using a perameterized constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I'm currently writing a code that takes in information from a file, and then fills an array with the object `Request` (which I've already written in another java file) based on the information in the file. This is what I have so far in my `main` method

```
Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please input the file name that you would like to be read into reqMover");
String thisFile = userIn.next(); 
FileReader inReader = new FileReader(thisFile);
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inReader);

ArrayList<Request> newReq = new ArrayList<Request>();

do{
    newReq.add(Request(inFile.nextInt(), inFile.nextInt(),
                       inFile.nextInt(), inFile.nextInt()));
    inFile.nextLine();
}while(inFile.hasNextLine());
```

This code resides in a java file called `reqMover`. This problem that I'm having is that the compiler is telling me "The method `Request(int, int, int, int)` is undefined for the type `reqMover`" even though that method is the constructor I created in the other class. Is there something special I need to do to load the `ArrayList` using this constructor?

Comment: You need to use the "special" keyword: `new Request(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are calling the Constructor of Request Class
To create the instance or calling annoymus object you need to use **new** operator.
If not i.e you are not calling the constructor you need to define a method with the signature of

```
Access-Specifier return type Request (type param1, type param2, type aram3, type param4){ 
  //handle your actions
}
```